# Is there a way make perl compilation fail if a hash key wasn't defined in the initial hash definition?

Tags: perl, hash, compiler-errors

All keys used should be present in the initial %hash definition.

```
use strict;
my %hash = ('key1' => 'abcd', 'key2' => 'efgh');
$hash{'key3'} = '1234'; ## <== I'd like for these to fail at compilation. 
$hash{'key4'}; ## <== I'd like for these to fail at compilation.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is something called a class. You might need that.

Answer (score 8):

The module [Hash::Util](https://metacpan.org/module/Hash%3a%3aUtil) has been part of Perl since 5.8.0. And that includes a 'lock_keys' function that goes some way to implementing what you want. It gives a runtime (not compile-time) error if you try to add a key to a hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Hash::Util 'lock_keys';

my %hash = (key1 => 'abcd', key2 => 'efgh');
lock_keys(%hash);
$hash{key3} = '1234'; ## <== I'd like for these to fail at compilation. 
say $hash{key4}; ## <== I'd like for these to fail at compilation.
```

Answer (score 5):

[Tie::StrictHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aStrictHash) dies when you try to assign a new hash key, but it does it at runtime instead of compile time.

Comment: So it sounds like it does the same as the standard Hash::Util::lock_keys function.

Answer (score -4):

```
use strict; 
my %hash = ('key1' => 'abcd', 'key2' => 'efgh'); 
my $ke = 'key3';
if (!exists $hash{$ke}) {
exit;
}
```

Comment: If you really require this at compile time, put it in a `BEGIN` block.

Comment: -1: This requires you to manually test the existence of each and every hash key each and every time you use the hash, which is antithetical to the question's desire that using a nonexistent key should fail automatically.